# Why are Javascript promises resolving out of order?

Tags: javascript, promise

I am attempting to use JavaScript promises in a project and the order of events are unexpected. I have narrowed it down into a small demo using a test promise.

```
testPromises = function(promiseNum){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        console.log ('handling promise '+promiseNum);
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log("resolving testPromises "+promiseNum);
            resolve();
        },2000)
    });
};
```

And then I call it like so:

```
testPromises(1).then(testPromises(2)).then(testPromises(3))
.then(function(value) {
        console.log('all promises resolved');
}, function(reason) {
        console.log('some promise was rejected');
});
```

This is the console output:

```
handling promise 1
handling promise 2
handling promise 3
resolving testPromises 1
all promises resolved
resolving testPromises 2
resolving testPromises 3
```

How can I get an output of:

```
handling promise 1
resolving testPromises 1
handling promise 2
resolving testPromises 2
handling promise 3
resolving testPromises 3
all promises resolved
```

Comment: Like @jacub.g has pointed out all your promises have all been created before the then function is even called.  A nice solution for this type of promise looping is to use a helper function.  Bluebird has a map function that has a concurrency option, in this case you could set this to 1.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`.then()` expects a function reference.  When you do something like this:

```
.then(testPromises(2))
```

you are executing the function `testPromise()` immediately and passing the return value to `.then()`.  This is almost never what you want (unless `testPromises()` returned another function) because for `.then()` to do its job, you MUST pass it a function reference (a function that it can call sometime later).  If you execute the function immediately, then `.then()` can't do its job and call it LATER.

Instead, what you want is this:

```
.then(function() {
    return testPromises(2);
})
```

Or, you could use `.bind()`:

```
.then(testPromises.bind(null, 2))
```

So, your whole chain would look like this:

```
testPromises(1).then(function() {
    return testPromises(2);
}).then(function() {
    return testPromises(3);
}).then(function(value) {
    console.log('all promises resolved');
}, function(reason) {
    console.log('some promise was rejected');
});
```

Or, using `.bind()`

```
testPromises(1)
  .then(testPromises.bind(null, 2))
  .then(testPromises.bind(null, 3))
  .then(function(value) {
        console.log('all promises resolved');
  }, function(reason) {
        console.log('some promise was rejected');
  });
```

---

If you're doing this a lot, you could make a curry wrapper for `testPromises()` that would return another function.  This is essentially what `.bind()` above was doing, but the syntax is a little prettier to use once you've declared your wrapper function.

```
function tp(arg) {
    return function() {
        return testPromises(arg);
    }
}
```

Then, because that wrapper returns another function, you could then do:

```
testPromises(1).then(tp(2)).then(tp(3))
.then(function(value) {
    console.log('all promises resolved');
}, function(reason) {
    console.log('some promise was rejected');
});
```

Comment: And if you find you're loading a long chain of these promises, you can write a function that takes a list of promises, and sets each one as the callback for the previous promise. Makes for a fun quick side job that is actually fairly useful.

Comment: yep, that was a very good explanation with multiple viable solutions. Excellent answer. Thank you.

Comment: "Instead, what you want is this:" - please explain the WHY behind this you don't even explain that.  Why do you want this verse the first

Comment: @PositiveGuy - Because `.then()` accepts a function reference as an argument.  That's what you HAVE to pass it for it to be able to do its job.  You need to pass it a function that it can then call later.  You don't want to execute the function immediately like the OP's code was.  I've edited my answer to try to make that clearer.

Answer (score 3):

This is the code to get the output you want:

```
testPromises(1).then(function(){
  return testPromises(2);
}).then(function(){
  return testPromises(3);
}).then(function(value) {
  console.log('all promises resolved');
}, function(reason) {
  console.log('some promise was rejected');
});
```

Promises are *resolved asynchronously*, but *created synchronously*.

```
testPromises(1).then(testPromises(2)).then(testPromises(3))
```

is more or less like doing

```
p1 = testPromises(1)
p2 = testPromises(2)
p3 = testPromises(3)

p1.then(p2).then(p3)
```

Since `new Promise` is synchronous, the first 3 lines you'll see will be

```
handling promise 1
handling promise 2
handling promise 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Well,

```
handling promise 1
handling promise 2
handling promise 3
```

occurs first because these calls are independent from the Promise workflow, they are executed right when you create each `Promise` object, because to do that you explicit execute each function like `testPromises(1)` and so on.

But the problem is that your call to `console.log('all promises resolved');` depends only on `testPromises(1)` being resolved, all your other promises are detached.

In order do sync them, each `.then` call have to return a Promise, and you can do it by using a `function` and returning the Promises `testPromises` function already returns.

```js
testPromises = function(promiseNum){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        console.log ('handling promise '+promiseNum);
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log("resolving testPromises "+promiseNum);
            resolve();
        },0)
    });
};

testPromises(1).then(function() {
  return testPromises(2);
}).then(function() {
  return testPromises(3);
}).then(function(value) {
        console.log('all promises resolved');
}, function(reason) {
        console.log('some promise was rejected');
});
```